# Tag name overflow on "top tags" section of user profile if tag name is long

Tags: bug, tags, design, profile-page

On the user profile page in the «Top tags» section there is a block for each tag, which contains:

1. Tag name
2. Score
3. Number of posts

If tag name is long, then the tag name may overflow, and parts (2) and (3) are not showing at all. It can be viewed in profiles of many users (all screenshots are from stackoverflow.com, but the error relates to all Stack Exchange sites):

- [@daniel-saguez-tezanos-pinto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5818517/daniel-saguez-tezanos-pinto)

  > [image]
- [@andy-nuryana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8067923/andy-nuryana)

  > [image]
- [@clalpha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6226546/clalpha)

  > [image]
- [@leonyannik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6859289/leonyannik)

  > [image]

Comment: Yep, this does affect other sites. For example, see [Random person](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/88985/random-person)'s profile.

Comment: Also [screenshot](http://peradev.net/images/se/tagtoowide.png)