# Profile of users with only three top tags is weirdly stretched if said tags are long

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, top-tags

I think this is related to, or the evolution of, [Tag name overflow on "top tags" section of user profile if tag name is long](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306372/), but I don't think they're dupes as this one had the tags overlapping each other, but this (updated?) bug has them push the border away.

[This user](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/60477/a-j-wallace) only has three top tags, all three of them having rather long names; as a result, their profile page is broken. Same thing for two other users who answered that question (and have no other tags): [Nic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/105086/nic) and [Hayden](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/104158/hayden).

[image: long tag names push the borders out of profile page]

I don't think it's Skynet trying to wreck SFF, as I found another instance on Movies.SE *(also related to time travel, though...)*. Namely, [Aparajit Basu](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/36886/aparajit-basu):

[image: same problem as above, but with Movies.SE's red theme]

Steps to reproduce:

- search for questions with several long tags. On SFF we have a lot of those, with the franchise tags, same on Movies; I wouldn't know for other sites.
- specifically, search for posts likely to be from passing-by users: `[long-tag-1] [long-tag-2] score:..x` with *x* depending on your site's voting habits. For Movies and SFF I had *x*=3, once again no ideas about other sites.
- select posters whose names you don't recognize as frequent users, and check if they only have 3 top tags and if the problem reproduces.

I'm on Windows 10, Firefox 64.0.2.

Comment: Also reproducable on Chrome and Windows 10.

Comment: I don't have any favorite or "watched" tags and my [profile pic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/223820/mari-lou-a?tab=profile) is weirdly stretched too

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think that's a different bug; I could've sworn I saw it reported a while ago but now I can't seem to find it :/

Comment: And ask yourself, why can't you find it? Because the bug page is a mess :)

Comment: I'm guessing this problem is no longer reproducible since the [changes to make profile pages responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370964/335251)?

Answer (score -1):

The weighted top tags in the user profile were changed to a list of equally sized elements during the responsive profile redesign, see [Now live: A fully responsive profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370964). (*"Weighted"* meaning the relative size of each tag box was a function of the percentage of the user's answers on that tag).

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371231) brought up the change specifically, in the comments the devs mention the possibility of revisiting the issue, but in the meanwhile the request has been marked [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

So currently the problem is fixed; with the responsive design the top tags and the boxes they're in shrink to the size of the screen without any overflow. Here's a screenshot of the example tags in the question at the lowest possible resolution:

[image: screenshot of top tags in user profile]